# A la española- idiomatic phrase or is it an abbreviation?

Tags: phrase

I saw this expression in an "Español Automático" podcast. It was something like *"ser feliz a la española"*.

I understand the general sense of it being, *"be happy the Spanish way"*. I wonder why it is not "al español / a los españoles".

Is it's meaning *"a la manera española"*? Or is it merely an isolated phrase?

Thank you

Comment: "a la + nationality" describes a style of the accompanying action or noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of similar usages and your surmise that there is a word or words suppressed here is correct. The [DLE recognises](https://dle.rae.es/espa%C3%B1ol?m=form) *despedirse a la española* as a separate phrase meaning what in English is called to take French leave. I have a recipe book with a recipe for *huevos a la flamenca*.

So in summary it is not an isolated phrase and a word like *manera* is understood.

Comment: thank you. Actually, yes, I also have heard of ''gambas a la gallega. ''So there seems to be many

Answer (score 0):

De forma indistinta, "Español" o "Española" es una manera de hablar, decir o referirse a lo que es natural, relativo y perteneciente a España y por tanto, no es una forma o frase aislada de referirse a algo relativo a España, sino que tiene más implicaciones.

De esta forma tenemos numerosos usos que se podrían expresar en un sentido masculino, tales como;

- Pollo a la española (Pollo al modo español).
- Beso a la española (Beso al modo español).
- Arroz a la española (Arroz al modo español).
- Tortilla a la española (Tortilla al modo español).
- Patatas a la española (Patata al modo español).

Este práctica, también se utiliza para hacer referencia a otros conceptos que nosotros interpretamos en un sentido especial de hacer las cosas en una determinada manera, ya sea hacia otros lugares nacionales como extranjeros.

- Bacalao a la vizcaína.
- Lomo de Cerdo a la alemana.
- Despedida a la francesa (Es cuando alguien simplemente sale por la puerta, sin despedirse o sin decir nada a nadie).
- Abrir el coche a la holandesa (Abrir la puerta de los vehículos con la mano contraria y actuar de modo inverso con objeto de proteger a ciclistas, usuarios de patinetes y motoristas, que pueden venir de improvisto).

La forma "**a la española**", se refiere igualmente "al modo español", decir entonces "*a la española*", *"a la francesa*", "*a la holandesa*"... se interpreta como la costumbre, manera u originalidad que se tiene en un lugar determinado y que los españoles entendemos, verdad o no, que es una forma típica de hacer las cosas en el sitio que se nombra, aunque esto no sea del todo cierto o corresponda a un estereotipo. Ejemplo "*Vivir **a la madrileña***", es decir,  "pasear con tu pareja sin tener nada previsto o saber donde ir o si te lo vas a pasar bien o mal".

- "Beso a la española" - beso a la *(manera de la nación*) española.
- "Tortilla a la española" - tortilla a la (*manera cocinada, de la nación*) española.
- "Vivir a la madrileña" - Vivir a la (*manera especial que tiene mucha gente de vivir en Madrid*) madrileña.